# r extract minutes between rows and add them up

Tags: r, time, time-series

I have the following dataset:

```r
structure(list(Zeit = c("11:35:00 AM", "12:43:00 PM", "12:48:00 PM", 
"12:53:00 PM", "12:58:00 PM", "1:03:00 PM", "1:08:00 PM", "1:13:00 PM", 
"1:18:00 PM", "1:23:00 PM", "1:28:00 PM", "1:33:00 PM", "1:38:00 PM", 
"1:43:00 PM", "1:48:00 PM"), SRB.konz = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0,0546352106", "1,89348740676", "14,16501124644", 
"33,21026613524", "45,19095110716", "51,16722074468", "46,13852290212", 
"38,99889779356")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to create a new column that contains the elapsed time, as minutes.

For some reason, I am facing issues with the time (Zeit) column.

Comment: All of your data are strings, have you tried to convert to a number-like time format? Also, it looks as if your `SRB.konz` column should be `numeric`.

Comment: yes, but neither lubridate nor anytime identify the time once I convert the time column to numeric :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to get the ellapsed time for each observation. In this case, I used the starting point as the first time of your `Zeit` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  # Convert string to POSIXct date-time object, using AM and PM
  mutate(across(Zeit, ~parse_date_time(.x, "%H:%M:%S %p"))) |>
  # Get minimum time to use it as the starting point
  mutate(mintime = min(Zeit)) |>
  # Calculate interval in minutes from the mintime to each Zeit
  mutate(mins = as.numeric(interval(mintime,Zeit),"minutes"))

#                  Zeit       SRB.konz             mintime mins
#1  0000-01-01 11:35:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00    0
#2  0000-01-01 12:43:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00   68
#3  0000-01-01 12:48:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00   73
#4  0000-01-01 12:53:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00   78
#5  0000-01-01 12:58:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00   83
#6  0000-01-01 13:03:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00   88
#7  0000-01-01 13:08:00              0 0000-01-01 11:35:00   93
#8  0000-01-01 13:13:00   0,0546352106 0000-01-01 11:35:00   98
#9  0000-01-01 13:18:00  1,89348740676 0000-01-01 11:35:00  103
#10 0000-01-01 13:23:00 14,16501124644 0000-01-01 11:35:00  108
#11 0000-01-01 13:28:00 33,21026613524 0000-01-01 11:35:00  113
#12 0000-01-01 13:33:00 45,19095110716 0000-01-01 11:35:00  118
#13 0000-01-01 13:38:00 51,16722074468 0000-01-01 11:35:00  123
#14 0000-01-01 13:43:00 46,13852290212 0000-01-01 11:35:00  128
#15 0000-01-01 13:48:00 38,99889779356 0000-01-01 11:35:00  133
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally times need a date to convert to a date time object like [`POSIXct()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html). So prepend today's date, create a date time, then extract the minutes using [`format()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/format.html).

```r
paste(Sys.Date(), dat$Zeit) |>
    as.POSIXct() |>
    format("%M") |>
    as.integer()

#  [1] 35 43 48 53 58  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
```

Answer (score 0):

Since latest R versions we can simply use

```
> strptime(dat$Zeit, '%H:%M:%S %p') |> strftime('%M') |> as.integer()
 [1] 35 43 48 53 58  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
```